# 99 volts on a light circuit/ceiling fan

Tags: wiring

I was recently doing some home improvement and had to temporarily remove a ceiling fan.  When I removed the ceiling fan, the previous installer had a braided “lamp wire” jumper from a the light switch feed. I thought this looked cheap and dangerous, but it was working as power.  I removed the “lamp cord” and replaced it with 14/2 copper wire.  I didn’t know exactly which was “hot” & “neutral, but I was getting 93 volts across both. I thought the wall switch might be bad, so I replaced it with a Leviton “single throw” rocker switch.
(Simple pass thru)  After installing the new switch, I was getting 99 volts (hot to neutral. Never checked hot to ground…?  I reconnected the ceiling fan to test it and the fan will not work now! I used a circuit tester and the whole fan, housing, wiring & light fixture were emitting voltage!!  Don’t know how much, but it wasn’t enough to notice by touch.
Anybody have a clue or ideas to what is going on with this circuit?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: 99 volts would indicate bad (loose) connection somewhere. Probably where you replace it

Comment: You newer told us what are you measuring at the switch box ? or did you ? Is your multimeter broken ? does it show 120 Volt in other places. ?

Comment: Sounds like phantom voltage coming off a DVM, which is too sensitive for the job and sees things that aren't there. **Why are you doing this work with the breaker on? You have way too much faith in the work of the last guy.**

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica if it is Phantom voltage, can one touch the wire, or short it to the ground

Comment: @Ruskes  Touching to check if it is phantom voltage can be a hair raising experience.  Much better to turn off power and hook up a light.  If it lights, not phantom.

Comment: @crip659 not everyone has  test lamp with clips, can I use multimeter on Amp setting

Comment: @Ruskes wow, you have stated 3 ideas all of which will go *fantastically badly* if you're wrong about it being phantom voltage.

Comment: @Ruskes I understand your concern and it does concern me as well!  That’s why I’m mystified as to what’s happening.  How can I check the circuit w/o power?  I don’t handle the wires, but I do have a “circuit tester”.   I don’t have all the proper tools an electrician would normally have either.

Comment: I am getting 118v on a separate switch, coming off the same “feeder box”.  Do you think I have the “power/neutral” reversed at the ceiling fan??

Comment: I ruled out the reverse polarity idea!